# Find all integer columns which are reaching its limits using information_schema

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I can get a list of all columns I want to verify the space available.

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE 
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
  COLUMN_TYPE = 'int(11)' AND 
  TABLE_NAME LIKE 'catalog_category_entity%';
```

Considering that int(11) is up to 2147483648 (not considering unsigned) I would like to calculate how much I am using from this range.

Individually I could check one like this:

```
select 
  max(value_id)/2147483648 as usage 
from 
  catalog_product_entity_int;
```

But I would like to do each on a nice way for all the columns found on the first query.

I would like to know if recursive CTE is the right resource in this case and how to do it or if there is a more elegant way of checking it.

I would like to have this nice quick way of checking without any external tools.

I've found this solution for postgres but I was wondering if I really need the function.
[postgres: find all integer columns with its current max value in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712604/postgres-find-all-integer-columns-with-its-current-max-value-in-it)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a solution for this task, but I'm hardly the only person to have done something like this.

```
select concat('`', table_schema, '`.`', table_name, '`.`', column_name, '`') as `column`,
  auto_increment as `current_int`, max_int, round((auto_increment/max_int)*100, 2) as `pct_max`
from (select table_schema, table_name, column_name, auto_increment,
  pow(2, case data_type
    when 'tinyint'   then 7
    when 'smallint'  then 15
    when 'mediumint' then 23
    when 'int'       then 31
    when 'bigint'    then 63
    end+(column_type like '% unsigned'))-1 as max_int
  from information_schema.tables t
  join information_schema.columns c using (table_schema,table_name)
  join information_schema.key_column_usage k using (table_schema,table_name,column_name)
  where t.table_schema in ('test')
    and k.constraint_name = 'PRIMARY'
    and k.ordinal_position = 1
    and t.auto_increment is not null
) as dt;
```

https://github.com/billkarwin/bk-tools/blob/master/pk-full-ratio.sql

That query is hard-coded for the `test` schema, so you need to edit it for your own schema.

The short answer to the question of "is my primary key going to overflow?" is to just alter it to `BIGINT UNSIGNED` now. That will surely last until the collapse of civilization.

In the same git repo, I have another similar script to check *all* integer columns, not just auto-increment primary keys. But it's not as much of a concern for other columns.

Comment: @RaymondNijland `0.00` just means that you are at least 99.995% away from reaching the limit. But it should be `round((auto_increment/max_int)*100, 2)` to avoid `out of range` errors for BIGINT.

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin that seems to work pretty well. The only issue I've noticed is when you have a compond primary key and then your query will calculate for both keys which one will be wrong. it is returning some outliers of 5233% in this case

Comment: Okay, the auto-inc column has to be the first column (at least in InnoDB), so you can also filter for `k.ordinal_position=1`. MyISAM tables allow the auto-inc column to be in a second position, but [I recommend never using MyISAM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17706717/20860).